# How do most companies sign their Android Apps?

Tags: android, deployment, signed

What is the best practice for an organization that will need to sign multiple Android apps?

Do we create one key and use that on all of the Android apps that we build?  My initial thought is that this is a good approach.

Or, do we create a new key for each Android app?

Does anyone know how an organization like Google or Rovio handles this issue?

Answer (score 1):

One of my clients uses a different key for each set of related apps. So apps that are usually used together share the same key, but unrelated apps have a different ones. They feel that segregating the keys this way is a good balance between ease of key management and minimizing exposure if a key ever gets disclosed (by a disgruntled employee, etc.).